# how to work around memory leak from webbrowser controls?

Tags: c, winapi, browser, memory-leaks, windows-embedded

I use the `iwebbrowser2` navigate to navigate over some local `html` files.

At each navigate, memory gets allocated and not released until I close my app! My `win32` (no `.net`, no `MFC`) app is running on a Windows embedded compatct 7 module.

Is there any workaround for that problem?

Comment: There should be a way to free this memory. I doubt anyone could help you, without seeing the code.

Comment: I think the only work around to a memory leak is get more memory or solve the issue.

Comment: How do you know it's a memory leak? E.g. `std::vector::clear()` does not release memory either, it keeps it around for a subsequent allocation.

Comment: ok, i got closer to the problem.
since im hosting a webbrowser control and using a touchscreen, the default IE gestures were acitve (like doubleclick causes zoom and so on).
so i set the [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Gesture]
"GestureCapabilities" value to 0  to enable my WM_GESTURE commands.
the problem is now that every callback(?) allocates memory.
even if i dont put any code to there!